# How to get the rounded colon time separator on iOS?

Tags: ios

Does anyone know if it is possible to use the time separator used in the statusBar and on the Lock Screen? I tried using the NSDateFormatter but it doesn't work (doesn't give the right character). It's also used in the Alarm Clock app.

[image: Image showing the rounded time separator]

Sadly this doesn't work:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
// or
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
```

Edit:

The normal colon of Helvetica Neue isn't rounded and rests on the baseline:

[image]

Comment: just use normal : why do you want NSDateFormatter?

Comment: Isn't that just the : character of helvetica neue?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't work' ? What are you seeing?

Comment: How about a replaceString... ?

Comment: Look at the "1" character.  It's a different font from your "normal" shot.  You need to use the right font.  (NSDateFormatter has nothing to do with the fonts used.)

Comment: The "1" character in the first shot is from Helvetica Neue Thin, the others are Helvetica Neue Light. Both have the wrong ":"